# How to use ArchUnitNET to test an ASP .NET Core web app

Tags: .net-core, archunit

I have a ASP .NET Core web app, with following folder structure,

```
Solution xxx
  Project xxx
    Controllers
    Handlers
    Services
    Messages
    ...
```

I want to utilize ArchUnitNET to enforce architecture rules. Following is a unit test for naming of classes, we want to make sure all handler classes end with handler :

```
[TestClass]
    public class NamingRules
    {
        private static readonly Architecture architecture = new ArchLoader()
            .LoadAssemblies(typeof(ASampleHandler).Assembly)
            .Build();
        private readonly IObjectProvider<Class> handlerClasses = Classes()
            .That().ImplementInterface("IRequestHandler").As("Handler Classes");

        [TestMethod]
        public void HandlerClassShouldEndWithHandler()
        {
            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(Classes().That().Are(handlerClasses)
                    .Should().HaveNameEndingWith("handler").HasNoViolations(architecture));
            }catch (Exception  ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

All mine handler classes are under the handler folder, and extend from IRequestHandler (from mediatoR). But it seems even I have a handler class that does not inherit from IRequestHandler and has a random name, the test still pass. Can anyone help to tell what I am missing?

In the ArchUnitNET document, this code is to load your architecture,

```
private static readonly Architecture Architecture =
    new ArchLoader().LoadAssemblies(typeof(ExampleClass).Assembly, 
    typeof(ForbiddenClass).Assembly).Build();
```

After built, my web app has only one assembly. It doesn't seem matter what the ExampleClass is, any class defined in my app would work. I am a little bit confused about what the purpose of the architecture.

Also, following code, when I check those variables, I couldn't find meaningful names, which make it harder to debug the unit tests. Any suggestions?

```
private readonly IObjectProvider<IType> ExampleLayer =
    Types().That().ResideInAssembly("ExampleAssembly").As("Example Layer");

private readonly IObjectProvider<Class> ExampleClasses =
    Classes().That().ImplementInterface("IExampleInterface").As("Example Classes");

private readonly IObjectProvider<IType> ForbiddenLayer =
    Types().That().ResideInNamespace("ForbiddenNamespace").As("Forbidden Layer");

private readonly IObjectProvider<Interface> ForbiddenInterfaces =
    Interfaces().That().HaveFullNameContaining("forbidden").As("Forbidden Interfaces");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `.Check(Architecture)` at the end of your `IArchRule`s. See the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnitNET?tab=readme-ov-file#create-a-test).